# Installed WordPress without configuration screen

Tags: installation, configuration

Is there a way install WordPress without configuring it manually on configuration screen?

For example, by providing configurations in configuration file?

I'm talking about configuration as code fashion. Once webserver and db is up, WordPress is already configured using configuration file settings.

So, WordPress admin page is immediately will be available after raising up the webserver.

Comment: have you looked into WP CLI? If the database details are present in `wp-config.php` then WP will assume the installation has already occurred

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can bypass the first step of the installation by supplying a `wp-config.php` file with all the DB details (and hopefully you will not forget to change the secrets in it), but the second stage includes configuring the admin user, and this information needs to be stored in the DB therefor either the DB need to be "magically" set with this information or you will need to amend the install process to create it based on your configuration file.

tl;dr It is possible but unless you predict that you will need to automate the process for tens of sites (and you still need to create your configuration file per site) not sure it is worth the effort.